# Error local variable type mismatch, in Xamarin.Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am trying to build a solution in Xamarin with an android library that I imported.

The library come from a manufacturer called bbpos.

I have the following error message :

```
Error com.android.dx.cf.code.SimException: local variable type mismatch: attempt to set or access a value of type java.lang.String using a local variable of type byte[]. This is symptomatic of .class transformation tools that ignore local variable information.
```

I think it comes from the library but i dont know from where exactly.
Is there a way to know where is the problem ?

Comment: According to your description, you said that you have this error message when you use jar library in xamarin.android project? If yes, can you tell me how you use jar library,can you give more detailed info. I find article about using jar library, you can take a look:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/binding-java-library/binding-a-jar

Comment: Thank you for your time. Actually i am not using the library. There is an error at the building process of the solution. I have already went through this article. That's how i  integrated the Java library to the Xamarin solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case it my help someone else i have finally found the solution.

It turns out the compiler was the problem.

I went to the Xamarin.Android Properties, then went to the Android Options tab. In the Dex compiler field I selected d8.

Comment: ,It seems that you have solved your issue now, please remember to mark your reply as answer, thanks.