# From Xamarin.Forms to Xamarin.Android and back again

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am working with an imported library (.jar).
There are callbacks methods in this library that are called when something happen on the device.
The implementation of these class are in the Xamarin.Android project.

And the interface of my App is in the Xamarin.Forms project.

How to make them communicate : display the interface (forms), something happen on the device (android), do the treatment, then refresh the interface with the new data (forms).

Thank you for your help.

Comment: This question makes me wonder if you already solved the problem that you had a few hours ago? I'm referring to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58344368/error-local-variable-type-mismatch-in-xamarin-android/58345946#58345946 If yes, please mark it as answered so that no more time is spent on something that's already solved. :)

Comment: No, i didn't solved it. I am working with a different library.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a DependencyService to communicate between the interface- Xamarin forms, and Xamarin Android. [Here's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction) Microsoft's official documentation on this.

I also shared a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58297222/11104068) a few days ago where a developer used his Interface(Xamarin Forms) to do stuff so as to get an AndroidClientHandler on their device (Android), then refresh the interface with the new data which can be any result class in your case.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I am more looking for a way to change Xamarin.Forms pages when a callback method from Xamarin.Android is called. I dont see how to implement that with DependencyService.

Answer (score 0):

> How to make them communicate : display the interface (forms), something happen on the device (android), do the treatment, then refresh the interface with the new data (forms).

According to your description, you want to communicate between PCL and Android in Xamarin.Forms, If yes, I suggest you can use [MessagingCenter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center) to do this.

The Xamarin.Forms MessagingCenter class implements the publish-subscribe pattern, allowing message-based communication between components that are inconvenient to link by object and type references. This mechanism allows publishers and subscribers to communicate without having a reference to each other, helping to reduce dependencies between them.

Here is the article about MessagingCenter, please take a look:

https://acaliaro.wordpress.com/2017/11/30/communication-between-xamarin-pcl-project-and-xamarin-android-ios-project-in-xamarin-forms-applicatio/